# Vue3 Vuex Persist not saving data appropriately

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vuex-persist

I'm having a difficult time getting Vuex-Persist to work properly. Basically, not saving the data it should:

[image]

Secondly, it disappears upon refresh. Which defeats the whole point of the library.

Here is my store file:

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import Modules from "./modules";
import VuexPersistence from "vuex-persist";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence({
    restoreState: (key: any, storage: any): any => Cookies.get("my-abseil-v3"),
    saveState: (key, state, storage: any): any => {
        return Cookies.set("my-abseil-v3", state, {
            expires: 3,
        });
    },
    modules: ["Auth"],
});

export default createStore({
    plugins: [vuexLocal.plugin],
    modules: { ...Modules },
});
```

My Auth module code:

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import Modules from "./modules";
import VuexPersistence from "vuex-persist";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence({
    restoreState: (key: any, storage: any): any => Cookies.get("my-abseil-v3"),
    saveState: (key, state, storage: any): any => {
        return Cookies.set("my-abseil-v3", state, {
            expires: 3,
        });
    },
    modules: ["Auth"],
});

export default createStore({
    plugins: [vuexLocal.plugin],
    modules: { ...Modules },
});
```

And my `vue.config`:

```
module.exports = {
    transpileDependencies: ["vuex-persist"],
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                prependData: `@import "@/assets/css/components/_breakpoints.scss";`,
            },
        },
    },
};
```

This is per the [documentations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist) so not sure where I'm wrong.

Comment: Ended up using a different library. This would simply not work in Vue3...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried JSON.stringify and JSON.parse?

```js
const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence({
    restoreState: (key: any, storage: any): any => 
        JSON.parse(Cookies.get("my-abseil-v3")),
    saveState: (key, state, storage: any): any => {
        return Cookies.set("my-abseil-v3", JSON.stringify(state), {
            expires: 3,
        });
    },
    modules: ["Auth"],
});
```

Comment: Did not work :(. Actually gave me a type error to (string | undefined) can't be assigned to string.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```js
const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence({
  restoreState: (key, storage) => Cookies.getJSON(key),
  saveState: (key, state, storage) =>
    Cookies.set(key, state, {
      expires: 3
    }),
  modules: ["Auth"],
});
```

Comment: Ended up going with Vue persistdata plugin. It was about 100x easier to implement